# Extracting qualities in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Are there efficient methods for finding the number of all elements less than an element in a binary search tree?  I've been trying to find a procedure or implementation in C++, but I haven't been able to.  So say you had:

```
      8
    /   \
   3     10
  / \      \
 1   6      14
```

and you wanted to find the number of nodes less than 10, you could obtain 4.

Comment: Don't search. Think and code. You know how to traverse a tree? That's enough to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how many nodes are below of a given node (in constant time), you can simply do the following:

```
int BinarySearchTree::countLessThan(const Node *n, const T &value) const {
    if (n->value >= value) {
        // The value has to be in the left sub-tree, so continue searching there:
        if (n->left)
            return countLessThan(n->left, value);
        else
            return 0;
    } else {
        // The value has to be in the right sub-tree, so continue searching there
        // but include the whole left sub-tree and myself:
        int count = 1;
        if (n->left)
            count += n->left->count();
        if (n->right)
            count += countLessThan(n->right, value);
        return count;
    }
}
```

Start the algorithm on the root node:

```
int BinarySearchTree::countLessThan(const T &value) const {
    countLessThan(root, value);
}
```

A live example can be seen here: http://ideone.com/JcpjeK

It runs on the following tree (I swapped 14 and 10, so 10 can be a left child of 14. This is because my quick and dirty BST implementation only allows a right child if there is already a left child):

```
      8
    /   \
  3       14
 / \     /
1   6   10
```

Comment: I wonder why did you use `if-else` instead of `?:`. It would make unreadability more consistent.

Comment: @Abyx :) I have to say: My code started having less branches in the expressions, so it was readable. After editing it a few times, it got more and more ugly. I cleaned it up now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int res = countLessThan(root, value, 0); // res is your answer
```

Then implement this:

```
int BTree::countLessThan(node *currNode, int value, int count)
{            
        if(currNode->left != NULL)
                count = countLessThan(currNode->left, value, count);

        if(currNode->value >= value)
                return count;
        count++;

        if(currNode->right != NULL)
                count = countLessThan(currNode->right, value, count);

       return count;

}
```

Comment: Static variable? This can be really error-prone, as it's not [re-entrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). (Which means: Two parallel executions of your function affect each other.)

Comment: Your class uses a static variable to count the elements. So even if the programmer uses different BSTs, both use the same static variable. Your code doesn't return the number of elements which are `<=`, but the first which can be found, which is not what has been asked for. (And no, the first found is not the smallest one: In the example in the question, try to find the element which is `<= 100`. You would return 8, which is non-sense.)

Comment: You want to write a static variable in a header which is used within your code. The user doesn't have control over that. So the **same** variable is used by **different** threads in **any** scenario. This even doesn't have anything to do with BSPs.

Comment: @Telkitty: Why are you assuming that programmers are not idiots. Let alone that they know the whole code base of a program (unlikely, most applications are large enough that a team builds it (so knowing when a tree is searched in all situations is unreasonable)). You should be writting code that can't be broken. Not code that is only broken if not used smartly.

Comment: @Telkitty: If you write this in an interview you ain't getting the job. If you write this as the result for an assignment your are getting an E. Simplicity is the best. But you are not making it simpler just worse. If you are going to bother to answer the question take the time to make it usable piece of code (couple of extra parameter and it would have worked its not as if I said you needed to implement the visitor pattern).

Comment: Your solution is now functionally correct but still performing very bad (linear time), as it doesn't make use of the fact that BSTs are sorted.

Comment: @Telkitty: I don't think your code is any prettier than the leading question. Your contains a lot less detail or explanation on how it works. So if the leading question got 2 zero seems appropriate. And the time it took you to get it correct means that nobody saw your correct answer.

Comment: @LokiAstari Yes, you are right, there are plenty of dumbass programmers who 1) upvoted for a fundamentally wrong answer 2) went around pointing fingers at other peoples answers when his own answer did not work 3) got some other idiots to back him up who instead of focusing on programming logic, focused on something trivial (no, if it does not work in single thread, it will not work in a multithreading environment either).

Comment: @Telkitty: Its sad that you think that (or that your code was worth getting higher marks). 1) The top answer works and is OK, 2) your code was pretty awful and needed fixing. 3) I don;t think there is any conspericy here on SO. Best answer gets the votes. 4) Yes you should read that some more. 5) If you put more effort into a good answer you may get somewhere. But with relatively crap code and an attitude its unlikely to get you far. PS. I still think the best answer is from Alex B below;even if it got -1. Simple to the point and works (also uses code that is already tested and known to work).

Comment: @Telkitty: At least you fixed our code. But it is still O(n) compared to O(ln(n)) of the accepted answer (Though I don't believe that would happen in real life). Your code is no neater than the accepted answer and both answers are much more complicated than the elegant solution using the STL (which is also O(n)). So good bluster but your code just does not hold up on close inspection.

Comment: @LokiAstari best answer got the worst vote count, precisely my point isn't it? P.S. I did not say my answer was the best, I merely pointed out how retarded votings in this thread have been.

Comment: @Telkitty: Why did you note vote for the best answer? Its just the best answer in our opinion (the majority disagree). Other people pointed out that its not really about using the STL but about using the BST (I disagree but that is just an opinion).

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are using `std::map` or `std::set` as your BST, you can use [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound) member function combined with [`std::distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/):

   ```
   auto count = std::distance(bst.begin(), bst.lower_bound(target));
   ```
2. Otherwise, you can use an [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound) function, however it will it's only optimal with flat containers (`std::vector`), because it assumes that the container implements random access iterators.

   ```
   auto count = std::distance(
       bst.begin(), std::lower_bound(bst.begin(), bst.end(), target));
   ```

Comment: Depending on the implementation of the binary heap this is not possible.

Comment: @leemes: Why is this not possable. Seems like a very resonable answer to use the standard algorithms. It makes the assumption that the binary tree has implemented an iterator (not unreasonable assumption as most C++ containers have iterators (and std::set has an iterator and is most likely implemented as a binary tree)).

Comment: @Alex B: A binary tree is unlikely to have random access iterators.

Comment: @LokiAstari Yes that was my assumption. You typically store it as a vector, but this is not sorted (top-down, left-right order). Only if the BST is stored as a sorted list (depth-first order), the standard binary search methods work, since they except a sorted sequence. But in this case, you didn't implement a BST, but just a sorted sequence.

Comment: @Loki yes well... A flat container gives you the theoretical minimum. There was no information given about the representation of the BST.

Comment: Seriously? "If you are using std::map as your BST representation" A typical `std::map` implementation *is* a BST. Why should he implement his BSP as a map? Containerception?

Comment: @leemes: Why would you implement a BST if you can use a std::set!

Comment: @LokiAstari For example, to find the number of elements smaller than a particular number in less than linear time ;)

Comment: @leemes or "use map as a BST", whatever, now you are just being pedantic.

Comment: Anyway, I guess that the question is about learning data-structures. So he should not use an existing data-structure already solving the issue by 99%. If he just needs a BST, he'd find enough free implementations in the internet.

Comment: @leemes: I know your answer could potentially work in `O(ln(n))` but in reality that is not going to happen. TO make it work you would need to store the number of child nodes in each node as a count. The problem here is then maintaining the count. It would change the insert from O(ln(n)) to O(n) or worse. SO you are only going to do that if you are searching for a lower bound count a lot more than you are going to spend time on inserting. So in reality your search is also O(n). Thus since both solutions are O(n) in complexity this is by far the better one.

Comment: @LokiAstari Insertion is still in `O(ln(n))` since that's the number of nodes for which you will update the count (the path to the root). Also, you won't even need to keep track of the count if your BST is (don't know the word for this) left-dominant (I mean: The left subtree of any node is "full" = its leafs have all an equal depth, as well as the depths of all leafs only differ by one), since then it can be calculated implicitly. And as long as I remember correctly, this is how balanced BSTs are typically implemented. But I might confuse this with Binary Heaps...

Comment: @leemes: I would assume (since it was a BST) you would keep it balanced on insert. That is why I would expect an increase to O(n) for insert as any re-balancing is going to require a re-count of all nodes below the re-balance point.

Comment: @Loki "any re-balancing is going to require a re-count of all nodes below the re-balance point". Tree rotations used for balancing red-black tree (i.e. common std::map/set implementation) is local operation thus add/remove would still be O(log2(n)) operation